# Community poll: Do we want a banner warning against AI generated answers?

Tags: discussion, status-review

This [recent Meta-Post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/395881/841946) announced that:

> Sites can now request to enable a banner to warn about their policy on AI-generated content.
>
> We will initially offer two banner text options that all sites in the Stack Exchange network can opt-in to. Those options are the following:

**Option A** "not allowed"

```
**Reminder**: Answers generated by Artificial Intelligence tools are not allowed on [Site Name]. Learn more
```

**Option B** "citation needed"

```
**Reminder**: Answers generated by Artificial Intelligence tools must be cited on [Site Name]. Learn more
```

Hopefully, this will reduce the number of low quality, AI generated answers.

To participate in this poll please **give one of the answers below an upvote** to vote for the respective option. Please don't down-vote any options, even if you don't agree with them.

If you have any questions, please leave a comment to the question, not to any answer.

The one option with the most upvotes will be communicated to the Community Management Team.

Answer (score 2):

We should activate the banner that says

> Answers generated by Artificial Intelligence tools **are not allowed** on [Site Name]. Learn more

Comment: I've generally found that likely AI-generated answers are *at best* low quality; considering we're dealing with living creatures here, allowing advice that's no better than poor and can quickly and easily slide into being bad or dangerous is not a route I want to go down.

Answer (score 0):

We should activate the banner that says

> Answers generated by Artificial Intelligence tools **must be cited** on [Site Name]. Learn more

Answer (score 0):

We should **not activate any of those banners.**